# Parameter estimation - uniform random variable

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, uniform-distribution

Suppose I have $n$ uniform random variables (iid) over $[0,\theta]$ and I want to build a confidence interval for $\theta$. Let $\bar{X_n} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} X_k$, I am asked to show that $\frac{\bar{X_n}}{\theta}$ does not depend on $\theta$, but I don't visualize this intuitively. I tried to write $$\frac{\bar{X_n}}{\theta} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{X_k}{\theta}$$ But I don't see how $\frac{X_k}{\theta}$ is independent of $\theta$.

Thank you

Comment: What is the distribution of $\frac{X_k}{\theta}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively - if $X \sim U[0, \theta]$, then dividing by the length - $\theta$ simply "standardize" the variable, namely restrict it to $[0,1]$. Formally, let $Y = X/\theta$, then
$$
F_Y(y)=\mathbb{P}(X/\theta\le y) = \mathbb{P}(X\le\theta y)=F_X(\theta y)=\frac{\theta y}{\theta} = y, \quad \forall y\in(0,1]. 
$$ 
Namely, $Y \sim U[0,1]$, that is independent of $\theta$.